# How can I read all characteristic of a BLE device with Queque List in a for cycle?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im' building an app that download all information from a BLE device. This device, can storage the information in your flash memory. The BLE device have 2 characteristic. So I'm building a code to download all information from it.
I have create a Queque of charactersitic to read, then I have a for cycle to read these characteristic.
To do this, I have implement a class that extends "Service"

This is my code:

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            continuaLetturaForza = true;
            continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;
            int counter = 0;
            while(continuaLetturaForza || continuaLetturaTemperatura){
                counter++;
                Log.v("CICLO WHILE", counter+"");
                if (currDevice != null) {
                    if(ReadQueue!= null && ReadQueue.size()>0){
                        for(int index=0; index< ReadQueue.size(); index++){
                            mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
                            /*try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }*/
                        }
                    }
                }else{
            //TO DO
        }
            }
            if(gattClientCallback!=null && mGatt != null)
                gattClientCallback.disconnectGattServer();
        }
    };
```

If I try to start my application, I can see **ReadQueque** List with my two characteristic, so I read characteristic 1 and characteristic 2 but effectively the system real only the first characteristic.

But if I uncomment this line of code:

```
/*try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }*/
```

all system found and I can read Characteristic 1 and 2. If I don't insert Thread.sleep, I read only the first characteristic.

Why ?

Comment: You cannot call readCharacteristic again until onCharacteristicRead is called. Actually you cannot perform any GATT operation until the corresponding callback has been called for the previous operation. So you need to reconstruct your code to continue execute one queue element when onCharacteristicRead is called (beware of concurrency issues if you access the queue from multiple threads).

Comment: @Emil thanks for your comment, do you have any suggestion to do this ?